# How to make fixed width for separator inset for UITableview in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using Xcode7.3.1 with Swift. I my view controller consists of UITableView and i need to set fixed width for separator inset using default cell.Please go through the following image.How to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: There is no default way to do this...try adding uilabel or uiview of height 1 and the desired width at the bottom of the cell content view...

Comment: put UIview as separator fill with grey color and set bottom ,lead,trailing constraint with fix height

Comment: @Anish웃 you meant that need to use custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set inset of separator in tableview same as below screenshot :

[image]

Programatically :

```
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, cell.frame.width/2) // modify width as per your need
```

Comment: I tried this but width vary depend up on each ios devices

Answer (score 0):

If You are using custom cell, then add a `UILabel` or `UIImageView` in the contentView of cell with fixed width constraint..

For example following constraints will make the separator fixed width

```
Leading - 10
Bottom - 2
Fixed Width - 100 (In my case)
Fixed height - 1
```

**NB :** Make the default separator style as None like this

```
self.tblView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
```

Or you can set it in story board too.

See my output :

[image]